# Adding a Command Within C# Get/Set Shorthand

Tags: c#, getter, setter, shorthand

Here is my understanding of C# get/set shorthand. The long way of defining a property in C#:

```
private int myVar;

 public int MyProperty
 {
  get { return myVar; }
  set { myVar = value; }
 }
```

We can shorten it by typing:

```
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

I have lots of properties defined, and each property always calls a function when it is set. Is there any way we can implement this using the shorthand method? Example of the long way I'm doing:

```
private int myVar;

 public int MyProperty
 {
  get { return myVar; }
  set { 
     myVar = value;
     //This function gets called every time the setter is called
     MyFunction();
  }
 }
```

Instead of doing this long method for the bunch of properties I have, is there any way to shorten it? Example [Does not work but I want something that looks like this if possible]:

```
public int MyProperty {get; set {MyFunction();}; }
```

Thank you!

Comment: just add a body to the get statement. `public int MyProperty { get { return <someValue>; } set { MyFunction(); } }`

Comment: Microsoft created an API for that in Visual Studio Code, see: [IntelliCode API Usage Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/intellicode/intellicode-api-usage-examples), there is also such a page for Visual Studio.

Comment: @Sorceri unless I'm understanding it wrong, by adding the body and doing ```return <someValue>``` wouldn't I still have to create my private variable for <someValue>? and then I'd have to add the ```<someValue> = value``` in the set command, which is then back to the original long form?

Comment: It rather seems like you designed your class incorrect/inefficient. How many properties does your class have? If you call a function within your properties setter I recommend sticking to the good old long way you showed as your first example.

Comment: @Max I'm working on a WPF project. Every time a property changes, I have to call an OnPropertyChanged(); function in order for the GUI to update. That means every property I want to be binded to the GUI needs this function. I have 20-50 properties right now and I only see that number growing.

Comment: @teriyakiforandy You need to show more of your classes code / properties otherwise it is unclear if the structure can be changed. Why does your UI need 20-50 event updates from a class?

Comment: @Max Throughout the different pages of the UI, there are many different properties that I reference and they should all change dynamically. I guess I'm not asking if a structure change can be implemented in the class itself, I just wanted to know if there was a shorthand command that I was unaware about. I'm just using the 'propfull' shortcut to quickly define properties, but the code gets long and messy from all the variable declaration with private/public fields and getter/setters.

Comment: @teriyakiforandy You could implement a custom Dictionary by deriving from `IDictionary<TKey, TItem>` and implement a `OnItemChanged`, `OnItemAdded`, `OnItemRemoved` event. this would reduce the amount of work for the getter/setter but would also make the properties less visible. Another option would be to use the project settings or a config file and a class to access those properties there.